# Google OAuth showing 'GSI_LOGGER The given client ID is not found

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I want to integrate authentication with Google in a web application.
In order to understand how it is working with the new react-oauth/google package, I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-adding-google-login-react-app/) step by step.

It doesn't work for me, even few hours after creating the OAuth Consent Screen and Credentials in Google Console.

The error is always:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
followed by
[GSI_LOGGER]: The given client ID is not found.

Any indication to what i might be doing wrong is appreciated.
Using React 18.2.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please find client ID in [OAuth 2.0 Client IDs] table from your google project:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=your_project
The clientId should be something like: 47...xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com

Then in your html file you should use this value for client-id like this:

```
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="47...xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-context="signin" data-ux_mode="popup" data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/auth" data-auto_select="true"
    data-itp_support="true">
</div>
```

This should work! I had the same issue and I solved it.

Comment: Thank you hoang, this seems to work better. Do you have any code for showing the SignIn button which would show with component GoogleLogin from @react-oauth/google?

Answer (score 0):

The Error probably means google doesn't recognise the clientId you provided.

Cross-check your clientId properly, make sure it's very correct without it having any improper space at the end of the string or beginning of the string.

I had this same issue with the same @react-oauth/google package and it was just a typo error on the clientId.

Hope this helps